# простая сортировка от большого к малому

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть div элементы, необходимо по клику сортировать элементы от малого к большому, как это можно сделать или при помощи какого плагина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать `tablesorter`. Если вам для JQ плагин нужен.

Сортировка при клике на `<th>`теги.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Номер</th>
      <th>Дистанция</th>
      <th>Бег</th>
      <th>Велосипед</th>
      <th>Время</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>12.23 КМ</td>
      <td>0.23КМ</td>
      <td>50.00 КМ</td>
      <td>11.40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1.23 КМ</td>
      <td>0.23КМ</td>
      <td>150.00 КМ</td>
      <td>1.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3121.23 КМ</td>
      <td>40.23 КМ</td>
      <td>1000.00 КМ</td>
      <td>21.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>123.23 КМ</td>
      <td>70.523 КМ</td>
      <td>500.00 КМ</td>
      <td>10.40</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Будет ли работать плагин, если вместо table используется div?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и предоставленный пример